# How to earn money enough to live a contented life without killing social and family life?

Tags: salary, work-life-balance, overtime, workload

I live in a third world country where middle class like me spends majority of day working. People seem to have no interest in anything other than work sleep circle. After finishing my proportional study life I just entered in this work phase of life. But this seems to be unbearable.

I want a life where I:

- Shouldn't be asked to work more than 8 hours.
- Want to work net 8 hours in 24 hours when I like. No fixed routine.
- Don't need high pay. Minimal salary like $600 - $800 per month will be fine.
- Don't want stressed work that messes with mind all the day.
- Want to work with minimal responsibilities.
- Could have day/days off at expense of reduced income.

Probably business will be more suited as advised be friends who understand this or are in this situation. I am a web developer good at website development. Currently working at a stressful job which starts at 9 am and takes almost all day with frequent late sittings. I am interested in working as freelancer for clients in Europe/US where I could opt for workload that I can bear. But this is not working for me yet. Not getting reasonable work as I am new.

Sorry if I sounded stupid. But I will be thankful if advised by contented and successful friends, so I could settle my life.

**EDIT**
Consider review for "off-topic"

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/35857/how-to-earn-money-enough-to-live-a-contented-life-without-killing-social-and-fam

Comment: These two are different Q&A sites and have different user base and hence expecting different approach to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am web developer as well. I can tell you this, you can't avoid what is happening with you. I was in the same position you are now. Only thing you can do is learn, and do it fast, grow! There is a saying, only true entrepreneur is ready to work 80h a week to not work 40h a week.

Ofc you can take small html and css related projects which will earn you your wanted 700$ a month. But you should ask yourself is that really what you want? If you are good web developer that number should be 3 or even 4 times higher.

Start small, learn fast, be proactive, follow new technologies. I can safely say that i started small, working as web developer for private company earning 800$ a month. For the past 3 years I developed myself to become this IT professional who can scale applications create large systems and manage high workload. I earn about 2k a month and i am still not happy. I want more. Life is a constant development and learning!

Few tips:

- Start managing your time
- Learn every day something new
- Polish things you learned already
- Follow new technologies
- Create some goals for the following few years
- Motivate yourself constantly
- Be patient and grow you portfolio and resume.
- Look for new opportunities.
- Find the work you want!
- Live your life happy :)

You should always think a few steps ahead. You can't achieve something without sacrificing something. In your situation it will be working more than 8h a day.
Besides you will never get the job without fixed time if you don't have already finished projects on you portfolio. No employer want noobie who want to work from home without proving himself worth it. because remember they cannot manage you if you work from home, mostly it depends only on trusting you. And that is a risk most of the employers are not willing to take!

From what you have said you want, sounds like you have chosen the wrong profession. The things you want sounds more like unqualified work. I suggest rethink your priorities and motive more yourself.

Regarding how to not ruin your relationships with your family and friends. That is a hard one. As i said you cannot achieve something without sacrificing something. Family will always understand, that is how life works. If they don't we cannot help here, get you priorities straight. Friends, if they don't understand, than i can suggest you to rethink if they are good enough friends for your and not dragging you down with them. You live your life for yourself not for them. If they have problem with you working than reconsider beeing friends with them. If you are developing yourself and learning and communicate you will soon find new friends which have same interests. Remember be the one who create friends not the one who is created a friend. What i am trying to say, be with people who will encourage you and motivate you.

Comment: Thanks for a great suggestion and help. I have been learning new technologies consistently and am very good and website development. Just wanted suggestions for have lenient time bounds.